# Issue with Binarysearch-Algorithm code

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

So I've been looking for my mistake in this code for 10-20 minutes, but I still couldn't find any mistake. However I found out (after finally adding a systemout) that somethings wrong with my "middle" Integer because it's < than the lowest number (start)

Any help is appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
public class BinaereSuche {

public static int intList[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512};


public static int bineareSuche(int number){
    int start = 0;
    int end = intList.length -1;
    boolean found = false;

    while(found == false){ 
        int middle = (end - start) / 2; 

        if(number > intList[middle]){ 
            start = middle + 1;
        }else if(number < intList[middle]){ 
            end = middle - 1;
        }else
            return middle;
        found = true;
        System.out.println(intList[start] + " <--> " + intList[end] + " => " + intList[middle]);
    } return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(bineareSuche(32));
  }
}
```

The sysout gives me`32 <--> 512 => 16
-1` where as 32 is the start number, 512 is the end number and 16 is the middle number between 512 and 32 which is obviously wrong.

p.s. I have been looking for answeres here on SO but still couldn't help find my problem -- If anyone is curious about how it works (if you don't already know): [Here's a picture](http://flylib.com/books/2/300/1/html/2/images/08fig02.jpg)

Comment: Hint: there is an unconditional `found=true` in your `while` loop. So the loop will never execute more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line is wrong:

```
int middle = (end - start) / 2;
```

try:

```
int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
```

Consider end=10, start = 9.  Your approach will calculate middle = 0.

Comment: It's not the only bug. Try searching for another value than 32. (See my comment above.)

Comment: @WhiteViking Oh yea, sorry forgot to reply after I've changed the code. Even though I didn't quite understand why the boolean changed to true because it shouldn't have changed (?), I deleted the boolean and changed that to:  ´while(start <= end){...}´ and it perfectly worked.